# Instalar certificado .CER.PEM Linux Centos7

Tags: apache, certificado-digital

Necessito instalar um certificado para um webservice no Apache (Centos7).
Os arquivos que nos enviaram são estes:

xxx.cer.pem

xxx.pfx

Alguem poderia me informar como eu faço a instalação destes certificados ?
Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Conforme esta resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8774631/1518921) você precisa primeiro converter o pfx para ser suportado no apache, usando `openssl`.

Primeiro instale-o (se não tiver instalado):

```
yum install openssl
```

Navegue até a pasta aonde esta o `xxxx.pfx` e depois no terminal use os seguintes comandos para converter o certificado:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in xxxx.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out xxxx.cer
openssl pkcs12 -in xxxx.pfx -nocerts -nodes  -out xxxx.key
```

Depois procure o arquivo na pasta do apache chamado `host.conf` ou `ssl.conf` (ou talvez esteja tudo dentro de `httpd.conf`) e procure o `<VirtualHost>` desejado, no caso o HOST deve ter preferencialmente a **porta 443** por exemplo `<VirtualHost *:443>` (certificado para todos hosts), então você deve apontar o local do arquivo .cer no `SSLCertificateFile` e apontar o local do .key no `SSLCertificateKeyFile`

Um exemplo seria:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:443>
 ...
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /caminho/para/xxxx.cer
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /caminho/para/xxxx.key
 ...
</VirtualHost>
```

> **Nota:** Se as flags do SSL devem estar dentro de um VirtualHost que seja do HTTPS, se fizer no host errado vai dar problema, um exemplo errado:
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80>
> ...
> SSLEngine on
> SSLCertificateFile /caminho/para/xxxx.cer
> SSLCertificateKeyFile /caminho/para/xxxx.key
> ```

O módulo SSL deve estar habilitado:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Depois é só reiniciar o Apache

Comment: Prezado Guilherme. Obrigado pelo contato. Após realizar estas alterações, o acesso passou a ser realizado apenas por HTTPS. Mas precisamos que o acesso permaneça em HTTP. Este certificado que desejo instalar, é para o nosso webservice conectar em outro webservice externo. O Certificado em questão foi emitido pelo webservice externo.

Comment: @RicardoPardimClaus então você mexeu em algo a mais, note que o exemplo está assim `<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:443>`, o 443 indica porta para HTTPS, se você não colocou no virtualhost correto vai ocorrer mesmo problemas.

Comment: @RicardoPardimClaus você viu a minha ultima edição da resposta? Eu coloquei a explicação do uso do `VirtualHost`, veja se lhe ajuda.